# Spring JarLauncher doesn't load application.yml from dependency

Tags: spring, spring-boot, executable-jar, spring-config

My problem is similar to one described here (I don't override classpath explicitly):
[Spring application.yml not detected when running with -classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38852109/spring-application-yml-not-detected-when-running-with-classpath)

I have a SpringBoot application producing executable **app.jar** built with repackage goal.
I have **application.yml** in root context of **backend.jar** which is a dependency of **app.jar**.
I can run the app successfully from IDEA via MainClass:

```
SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
```

I can run the app successfully from terminal:

```
java -jar app.jar
```

However, the application fails to configure from application.yml when I run it locally as *CloudFoundry* does:

```
unzip app.jar
java org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
```

Spring will boot up and provide static content but fail at first attempt to access anything that requires data from configuration.

I've read through documentation and I can't figure out what is wrong with the classpath. From MANIFEST.INF I assume *java -jar app.jar* executes the same class as I do in the third example above.

Thanks for ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a **classpath** problem (duh!).

We had an 'forgotten' empty application.yml in dependency Y and an actual valid application.yml in our dependency X. Similar to the classes, only first occurrence of the resource on classpath is loaded by the classloader.

After enabling spring debug logging and examining *ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener* output one can see that the classpath order of dependencies within fatjar is **different** for the use cases described in question.

For **java -jar** nested JAR order seems to be **hashed**. For **JarLauncher** it is **alphabetical**.

Existing request to make this consistent: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9128

Comment: How did you solve the issue? I have the similar usecase where I need to lauch job using CommandLineJobRunner. I am using gradle bootRun task to lauch the mainClass CommandLineJobRunner with param. I am stuck with error : where datasource bean can't get initialized because application.yml is not picked.